# How to compute the gradient inside the Expectation

Tags: expected-value, calculus-of-variations, gradient-descent, bernoulli-numbers

Assume, we have a function

$$
\mathcal{E}(\phi)=\mathbb{E}_{z \sim \text { Bernoulli}(\sigma(\phi))}[f(z)]
$$

Here $z$ is a variable, and follow the Bernoulli distribution with parameters $\sigma(\phi)$, and $\sigma()$ is the sigmoid function. $\mathbb{E}$ is the Expectation, $f$ is a general function. How to compute the gradient

$$
\nabla_{\phi} \mathcal{E}(\phi)
$$

Thanks,

Comment: Generally speaking the expected value is an integral (or a sum). Can you write the expression $\mathbb{E}_{z \sim \text { Bernoulli}(\sigma(\phi))}[z]$ explicitly as a sum? ($f$ is not really a problem)

Comment: @Uskebasi feel free to edit the expression if necessary. Thanks a lot.